# How to compare the quality of research group?

Tags: ranking, research-group

There are metrics on the quality of universities (e.g., rankings) and individual researchers (e.g., Google Scholar), but I found it harder to judge the performance and impact of individual research groups. The ranking of the university, departments and the profiles of the leading researchers are usually clear indicators for the entire group.

Are there any other good metrics, indicators or properties that indicate the impact and performance of a research group?

Comment: How are you defining quality? The quality of a university is often operationalised quite differently from the quality of an individual researcher (e.g. research impact, staff levels, student experience, employment prospects for graduates vs. bibliometrics)

Comment: I'm not sure, I guess that is part of the questions.

Comment: You may want to edit the question to include that, although "what makes a research group high quality" seems like it could run foul of the SE rule about avoiding largely opinion based questions.

Comment: What about a meta-H-index: the largest number k so that there are at least k researchers with H-index at least k in the group. As the poet said, "I heard you like H-indices, so I used your H-indices to make a new H-index".

Comment: If this is for your career, I'm not sure how useful it is.  There are obvious benefits to affiliating yourself with a high quality institution or high quality individual researchers, but does average group quality really matter much beyond that?  Also "research group" is a relatively amorphous concept, and what you measure might be simply based on how the groups have been arbitrarily defined.

Comment: I think this is a very relevant question and I do not know why it did not received more attention

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the rate of citations for the individual researchers' publications? Go onto Google Scholar and see how many people cite the papers that are published by individuals from the group. You could also contact people within that field to ask them about the reputation of the group.